# Show that $f(x, y) = x^{1/3}\, y^{1/3}$ is not differentiable at the origin

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have a function $f(x, y) = x^{1/3}\, y^{1/3}$ and I have to show they it is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

So I thought I would show $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} f(x, y)$ does not exist. But I keep getting $0$ as the result. What are some other ways to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* Since $f'_x(0,0) = f'_y(0,0) = 0$, differentiability is equivalent to $f(x,y) = o(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$, i.e.
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^{2/3}y^{2/3}}{x^2+y^2} = 0,$$
which is false.

Comment: Can you explain where that equation came from?

Comment: By definition $f$ is differentiable at $0$ iff $f(x,y)=f(0,0)+f'_x(0,0)x+f'_y(0,0)y+o(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but what does that o notation mean?

Comment: The above expression means
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)-f'_x(0,0)x-f'_y(0,0)y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = 0.$$